# Make Programmatic Remember Me?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security

greetings all
i am using spring security 3.0.2
and my login form doesn't use the spring login configuration, it's a custom login form (i have to make it this way)
i was wondering how to make a user remembered programmatically 
if he checked the remember me checkbox
note: we have another login form that uses spring login configuration and uses Persistent Token Approach in remember me service.
so any ideas ?

Comment: all i want to do is to generate the cookies (series,token) for the user and save them in the database, my problem is in how to generate them, any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change how remember-me works you're going to need to extend `AbstractRememberMeServices` or `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` (based on exactly what you're trying to do).

You will then need to point Spring at your Remember Me implementation via the `services-ref` directive of the remember-me directive in the configuration xml file:

```
<remember-me services-ref="sword101CustomRememberMeServices" key="{GUID}" token-validity-seconds="3600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
```

If you can be a little more specific about your setup and your goals I might be able to provide more detailed assistance.

Grant

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do **RememberMe manually** during manually authorization,

First, you save an user in Security Context

```
@Autowired 
RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(currentUser, null, currentUser.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, auth);
```

}

Here's configuration

```
@Configuration
...
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Bean
    public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
    //      TokenBasedRememberMeServices if you don't want to persist token 
    //      return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("key", userDetailsService);
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices =
            new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("key", userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository());
    rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    return rememberMeServices;
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    db.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a custom form but still call the spring login url (j_spring_security_check).

Why don't you just use the RememberMe field (_spring_security_remember_me) on your custom login form?

Comment: i am not using the spring login url, i make the authentication in a custom controller, can i use the spring automatic remember me here ?